# What is an in-script code to terminate a script with an if function (when the value is not true)?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am intending to end a script right after an "if" logic, when the logic returns a "true" result. Here it is:

```
age=int(input("Enter your age: "))
if age<=18:
    print("You are not an adult. Please exit.")
    exit() **#here is where I need the code to terminate and exit.**
else:
    print("Your age is: ", age)
from datetime import date
print("This is the year ",date.today().year)
yr = date.today().year
yob=yr-age
print("You were born in the year: ",yob)
```

What would be the most appropriate command to terminate the sequence if the first "if" logic returns "true" i.e. if the age is below 18, the script should terminate. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to end the script. It's tough to say what you want to achieve, without sharing any code here. But still in general you can try this-

1- Use `pass` keywords

2- if you are using loop, you can use `break` keyword

3- if you are using a function, just return nothing if the condition is not true.

4- you can also use 'try and except' block

5- You can use `while` loop